# executing a certain web service based on a dropdown selection

Tags: javascript, angularjs

im new to angular and i had a question about how i would go about executing part of a function base on a dropdown selection. in the drop down selection i have a Mill location, and in the angular controller i want to use that location that was picked and only execute that particular webservice instead of executing all of them and making the user wait for them all to populate.

this is my controller

```
var CapitalRequestMultiMillInquiryController = function ($scope, $sce, $rootScope, $modal, $window, CapitalRequestService, PlantService) {


$rootScope.title = 'Capital Request Multi Mill Inquiry';
$scope.allMills = [];
$scope.mill = '';
$scope.jobNumber = '';
$scope.description = '';
$scope.amount = '';
$scope.amountOperator = '';
$scope.openOnly = '';
$scope.projectManager = '';

//$scope.allUsers = [];

//UsersService.getUsersWithId().then(function(objectTypes) {
//    $scope.allUsers = objectTypes
//});

//CapitalRequestService.searchMulti("http://tomcmmsweb.pca.com/CapitalRequest/Search", authenticatedUser.userName.toUpperCase(), $scope.selectedMill, $scope.jobNumber, $scope.description, $scope.amount, $scope.amountOperator, $scope.openOnly, $scope.projectManager).then(function (results) {
//    $scope.tomahawk = results;
//    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.tomahawk.length; i++)
//        $scope.tomahawk[i] = $sce.trustAsHTML($scope.tomahawk[i]);
//});


PlantService.getPlantId().then(function (mills) {
    $scope.allMills = mills
});

$scope.search = function() {
    //for each mill

    CapitalRequestService.searchMulti("http://coucmmsweb.pca.com/CapitalRequest/Search", authenticatedUser.userName.toUpperCase(), $scope.mill, $scope.jobNumber, $scope.description, $scope.amount, $scope.amountOperator, $scope.openOnly, $scope.projectManager).then(function (results) {
        $scope.counce = results;
        $scope.counce.forEach(function (item) {
           // item.projectManager = $sce.trustAsHtml(item.projectManager);
            item.jobNumber = $sce.trustAsHtml(item.jobNumber);
            item.description = $sce.trustAsHtml(item.description);
            item.amount = $sce.trustAsHtml(item.amount);
        });
    });

    CapitalRequestService.searchMulti("http://filcmmsweb.pca.com/CapitalRequest/Search", authenticatedUser.userName.toUpperCase(), $scope.mill, $scope.jobNumber, $scope.description, $scope.amount, $scope.amountOperator, $scope.openOnly, $scope.projectManager).then(function (results) {
        $scope.filer = results;
        $scope.filer.forEach(function (item) {
         //   item.projectManager = $sce.trustAsHtml(item.projectManager);
            item.jobNumber = $sce.trustAsHtml(item.jobNumber);
            item.description = $sce.trustAsHtml(item.description);
            item.amount = $sce.trustAsHtml(item.amount);
        });
    });

    CapitalRequestService.searchMulti("http://tomcmmsweb.pca.com/CapitalRequest/Search", authenticatedUser.userName.toUpperCase(), $scope.mill, $scope.jobNumber, $scope.description, $scope.amount, $scope.amountOperator, $scope.openOnly, $scope.projectManager).then(function (results) {
        $scope.tomahawk = results;
        $scope.tomahawk.forEach(function (item) {
          //  item.projectManager = $sce.trustAsHtml(item.projectManager);
            item.jobNumber = $sce.trustAsHtml(item.jobNumber);
            item.description = $sce.trustAsHtml(item.description);
            item.amount = $sce.trustAsHtml(item.amount);
        });
    });

    CapitalRequestService.searchMulti("http://tridentval.pca.com/api/Inquiry/Inquiry/CapitalRequestMultiMillInquiry/Search", authenticatedUser.userName.toUpperCase(), $scope.mill, $scope.jobNumber, $scope.description, $scope.amount, $scope.amountOperator, $scope.openOnly, $scope.projectManager).then(function (results) {
        $scope.valdosta = results;
    });

    CapitalRequestService.searchMulti("http://tridentder.pca.com/api/Inquiry/Inquiry/CapitalRequestMultiMillInquiry/Search", authenticatedUser.userName.toUpperCase(), $scope.mill, $scope.jobNumber, $scope.description, $scope.amount, $scope.amountOperator, $scope.openOnly, $scope.projectManager).then(function (results) {
        $scope.deridder = results;
    });

    CapitalRequestService.searchMulti("http://valcmmsweb.pca.com/CapitalRequest/Search", authenticatedUser.userName.toUpperCase(), $scope.mill, $scope.jobNumber, $scope.description, $scope.amount, $scope.amountOperator, $scope.openOnly, $scope.projectManager).then(function (results) {
        $scope.whiteMills = results;
        $scope.whiteMills.forEach(function (item) {
            item.jobNumber = $sce.trustAsHtml(item.jobNumber);
            item.description = $sce.trustAsHtml(item.description);
            item.amount = $sce.trustAsHtml(item.amount);
        });
    });

   }
};
```

and this is my dropdown.. its binded to the mill variable in the controller. im assuming an if else statement  but i dont know how to put this in angular speak.

```
        <div class="form-group">
            <select class="btn btn-info dropdown-toggle" style="width: 92%" ng-model="mill">
                <option value="">Select a Mill </option>
                <option value="608">Tomahawk Mill</option>
                <option value="610">Valdosta Mill</option>
                <option value="620">Counce Mill</option>
                <option value="622">Filer Mill</option>
                <option value="650">DeRidder Mill</option>
                <option value="651">Wallula Mill</option>
                <option value="652">Jackson Mill</option>
                <option value="653">International Falls Mill</option>
                <!-- <option ng-repeat="mills in allMills" value="{{mills.plantNumber}}">{{mills.plantName}}</option>-->
            </select>&nbsp;
        </div>

 <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-xl-12">
    <accordion close-others="oneAtATime">

        <accordion-group is-open="status.isFirstOpen">
            <accordion-heading>
                Capital Request - Counce Mill <span class="badge pull-right">{{counce.length}}</span>
            </accordion-heading>

            <table class="table table-striped table table-hover">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Job Number</th>
                    <th>Description</th>
                    <th>Amount</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat="item in counce">
                    <td ng-bind-html="item.jobNumber | addTargetBlank"></td>
                    <td ng-bind-html="item.description | addTargetBlank"></td>
                    <td ng-bind-html="item.amount | addTargetBlank"></td>
                </tr>

                </tbody>
            </table>
        </accordion-group>
```

Comment: Write a function on ng-change attribute where you can access the selected module and pass $event argument to function with your data and with help of $event you can access target element and using target element you can differentiate on which filed you have to make a server call

Comment: i edited my post as i put my controller contents twice. In the view ill add a ng-change right? and what ever other input the user what to refine his search with. then in the controller to can i compare the mill variable and execute if it is a match

Comment: i basically just did it but there is a huge draw back. i made if else statements comparing the mill variable and depending on what is chose at the time search is executed it will only execute that server call. BUT if i choose a different mill it will bring the new data in for that mill but the previous query is still displayed and i dont want that there .